# How to suspend ffmpeg file reading?

Tags: ffmpeg

My ffmpeg-based player plays a mpeg-ts file that downloaded from a server. I want my player be able to play the video file even it is being downloaded.

There is no problem if the download speed is faster than reading speed, otherwise my player crashs.
My question is that is there anyway to suspend ffmpeg file reading to wait for data available to proceed?

Comment: if your player crashes, there is something wrong in your code. What have you tried ? Do you use buffering ?

Comment: You can write your own ffmpeg-based player that will control the download process.

Comment: @SirDarius thanks, it seem i didn't handle the case well so it crashes. but the point i'm trying to ask here is that how to suspend the ffmpeg-reading to wait for more data from downloader. I use avio_open2(...) and av_read_frame(...) to read.

Comment: I can control the download process, but how can i control ffmpeg's reading